# How to change names of files in a directory to random generated names?

Tags: bash, batch-rename, filename

I have many files with different names of different lengths. Extension of these files are jpeg.

How to change names of the files to random generated names?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run in the directory with the files:

```
for file in *.jpeg; do
    mv -- "$file" "$RANDOM.jpeg"
done
```

But there is a chance the random names will conflict since `$RANDOM` only gives numbers between 0 and 32767.

Better solution, thanks to [pbhj](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107016/how-to-change-names-of-the-files-to-random-generated-names/1107021?noredirect=1#comment1826277_1107021):

```
for file in *.jpeg; do
    mv -- "$file" "$(mktemp --dry-run XXXXXXXX.jpeg)"
done
```

There is still a chance the random names will conflict, but it's significantly smaller with 8 alphanumeric characters from `mktemp`. See [Anselmo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107088/301745) for guaranteeing no conflicts.

Comment: I wouldn't use $RANDOM which defaults to 5 digit numbers; instead I'd try `mktemp --dry-run XXXXXXXX.jpg`, 3 or more Xs get replaced by a random alphanumeric string of equal length.

Comment: In the proposed version, we can also string: `mv "$file" "$RANDOM.jpeg"` replace by string: `mv "$file" "$( gpw 1 20 ).jpeg"` or another string: `mv "$file" "$( pwgen 20 1 ).jpeg"`.  Where 20 - is number of characters in the file name.

Comment: @pbhj Thanks for mentioning! I'll add that in. Yeah, mine is a pretty lazy (but simple) solution.

Comment: **`--dry-run` here is on `mktemp` not on `mv` => files will be actually renamed :)**

Comment: Why use `--dry-run` at all? By passing it, you risk a clash and then you silently overwrite one of your earlier files. Not good. Just omit it, then `mktemp` can guarantee you a unique destination filename. That's the whole point of it. The only exception is if you've exhausted all possible combinations from the XXXXXXX pattern

Answer (score 4):

Using RANDOM is a limited approach. From BASH man: "RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between 0 and 32767 is generated."
So... No more than 32768 files! : )

Another, bigger, problem is the possibility of repetition.
You see, the problem of repetition affect any use of random generators, only with different probability of occurrence.

The use of mktemp can be a much better solution, but you must not use the --dry-run parameter, because this generate the name but does not guarantee that a file with that name doesn't exist. Used in that way it became only a kind of random generator.

So, my simple propose is:

```
for file in *.jpeg; do
    new_file="$(mktemp XXXXXXXX.jpeg)"
    mv -f -- "$file" "$new_file"
done
```

Step by step.

```
new_file="$(mktemp XXXXXXXX.jpeg)"
```

Running mktemp that way, it creates a file safely with a new random name, caring random repetition. It also output the name of the created file, that I catch in new_file.

```
mv -f -- "$file" "$new_file"
```

Running the mv with the -f force the renaming of the image to overwrite the new_file.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize `--dry-run` doesn't guarantee a unique file name. The manual isn't very clear about that - just says it's "unsafe" but doesn't define what "unsafe" means. Thanks!

Comment: @wjandrea It only guarantees a name is free at the exact *time of checking*, but doesn't protect it until the *time of use* from being taken by other programs. It could even issue the same name again itself if you haven't created the first yet as it's still free.  Also a security risk: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with a large degree of certainty that you won't get file names with similar names by having multiple`$RANDOM`s as follow:

```
for file in *.jpeg; do
    mv -- "$file" "$RANDOM-$RANDOM-$RANDOM.jpeg"
done
```

The possibility of getting the same name is `1/(32767)^3` in the above example.